# How to use unix home directory in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unix, home-directory

From the PostgreSQL tutorial, I saw a command like this:

```
COPY weather FROM ’/home/user/weather.txt’;
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use generic shortcuts to the current user's specific home directory in a UNIX environment instead of `/home/user`?

I tried `COPY weather FROM ’~/weather.txt’;` , but got:

```
syntax error at or near "~/"
```

Comment: If you use `psql`, `\copy` will expand a `~` the right way.

Comment: Note the pathname is handled by the server (the user need not even have a home directory there!). In practice the only practical path is /tmp, or a subdirectory of it (with some privacy concerns). `\copy` inside psql is handled by the client, and the path is supposed to exist at the client side.